# Floating text to the right of an image for a side bar

Tags: html, css

I came this far, but I just cannot seem to get the text `Product 1 Title` to appear to the right and at the top of the image beside it. The other text `seller` needs to appear below it.

Till this time, I tried everything from floating the image left, to almost everything else, but all I get are strange results. I've also tried several suggestions here on stackoverflow, but I suspect it has something to do with the rest of the css (which cannot be changed).

I've removed the rest of the body and css related to that, and posted only the problem here. Can you please help?

I've posted images of how it appears for me, and the results I'm trying to achieve.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uzcbt58/)

This is the part with the problem:

```
<div id="contentright">
            <div id="sidebar" class="clearfix">
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <img src="/resources/images/demo-1.jpg" style="float:left"><span style="margin-left:5px;">Product 1 Title</span><span>Seller</span>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <img src="/resources/images/demo-1.jpg" style="float:left"><span style="margin-left:5px;">Product 1 Title</span><span>Seller</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: Done this far]
[image: Layout trying to achieve]

Comment: I made a bit stripped down example http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/3uzcbt58/3/ %)P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.menu li {
    border-top:1px solid #ebebeb; 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    display:inline-block; /* added */
    width:100%; /* added */
    padding: 5px;
}
```

`float:left;` for `.image` was giving problem so the the bottom `<li>` was only getting the height of the text which was present in `<li>` by giving `inline-block` `<li>` will get full height here is the fiddle

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/3uzcbt58/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu li {
border-top:1px solid #ebebeb; 
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
overflow: hidden;//added
```

}

because the 'img' dom has floated,but the parent dom 'li' wasn't clean, so the img dom free to the domlist .

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to add `clear: left` to this class:

```
.menu li {
    border-top:1px solid #ebebeb; 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    clear: left;/*Add clear left*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3uzcbt58/4/)